# Samsung Knox library import intent package

Tags: android, samsung-knox, samsung

I'm try to use knox to handle the X-Cover with ptt key

I'm trying to implement a receiver like this:

```
String intentAction = intent.getAction();
if ("com.samsung.android.knox.intent.action.HARD_KEY_REPORT".equals(intentAction)) {
    int keyCode = intent.getExtra(com.samsung.android.knox.intent.extra.KEY_CODE)
    int keyReportType = intent.getExtra(com.samsung.android.knox.intent.extra.KEY_REPORT_TYPE)
    if (keyCode == KEYCODE_PTT && keyReportType == 1) {
        // XCover key pressed
    }
    else if (keyCode == KEYCODE_PTT && keyReportType == 2) {
        // XCover key released 
    }
}
```

But I can't see the intent package in the .jar library, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For receiving intents, you don't need the knox library. Just put the parameter at both `getExtra` methods in quotes. As you can see in the table at the [knox documentation](https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/knox-sdk/hardware-key-remapping-isv.htm#mag_0), their identifier is their value.